# If I have a regulated 5v supply how can I power a micro-usb b device?

Tags: power, usb

Let's assume I have a good solid 5v supply and I want to power a device, like the Raspberry Pi, via a USB micro-b connector.

What is the easiest and/or best way to go about this? Can I just hook the power up to one of the USB pins on a breakout board or is there something more to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be no problem to just wire to it, just remember the pinout (don't worry about type A or type B just leave pin 4 unconnected). Also you should technically be limiting the power on the USB power lines to 500mA to comply with USB standards. The RasPi, however, may need more than 500mA of power and be unstable if powered only from USB limited at 500mA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You rock, that's what I needed to know

Answer (score 1):

Just cut a regular USB micro-B cable, and connect your power source to it. The red wire is the +5V and the black one is the ground. leave the white and the green wires alone.